# Python Syntax Confusion

Tags: python

I am teaching myself python and am writing a few scripts to better understand certain things.  I was wondering why this returns 0 rather than 27.  If this were java I beleive it would return 27 (I initialized a variable and later called a function that changed the variable). What is going on?

```
result = 0;

def cube(x):
    result = x * x * x

cube(3)

print(result)
```

Comment: scoping. result inside function has no relation to the result variable outside. Edit: Also, there is no concept of having to "initialize" variables. Also, before you get bit by this: [names refer to values in python](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: avoid global variables...

Answer (score 2):

Your `result` variable is both defined outside the function `cube` as a global variable, and inside the function `cube` as a local variable, which is a completely different variable from the global one.

You can use the `global` statement to declare a variable as global for a function to update a global variable:

```
def cube(x):
    global result
    result = x * x * x
```

but global variables should be used sparingly; prefer a function that returns a value.

Comment: no you should _not_ use `global`. It sucks

Comment: One *should* not use a global variable, but this answer is correct if one *has* to use a global.

Comment: The downvote is too harsh.  However unlikely, there might be a legitimate use case for OP's question to change the `global` `result` instead.  @blhsing is just answering a bad question with its answer...  Although technically, it could have easily been `result = cube(3)`.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I closed as duplicate, as I should have done earlier.

Answer (score 2):

The result is unchanged because of the scope. This is the right way to do it.

```
result = 0 # redundant

def cube(x):
    return x * x * x

result = cube(3)

print(result)

# expect 27 here
```

Answer (score 0):

what you're looking for is this:

```
def cube(x):
    result=x*x*x
    print(result)
```

And then if you input `cube(3)` you'll get `27`. You first define what your function will do, and the can call it. If you want to store a variable you end it with `return result` and then you can do something like:

```
def cube(x):
    result=x*x*x
    return result

res=cube(3)
```

And then, `res` will be stored as an `int` equal to 27.

Also, variables that are not specified in the `return` statement will always be local, so you will not be able to recover them. Also, as stated above, you don't have to initialize variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not having a return, so then, print is taking the first result variable.

```
result = 0;
def cube(x): 
    return x*x*x   
print(cube(3))
```

So you dont need to use result in this case, but if you want, you can do:

```
result = 0;
def cube(x): 
    return x*x*x   
result = cube(3)
print(result)
```

I hope you answer your question, greetings!

Answer (score 0):

to make your program work, we need to use “global” keyword. We only need to use global keyword in a function if we want to do assignments / change to a global variable.

```
result = 0
def cube(x):
    global result
    result = x * x * x

cube(3)

print(result)
```

> If the global statement occurs within a block, all uses of the name
>   specified in the statement refer to the binding of that name in the
>   top-level namespace.

here you can read good explanation about [scope of variables in python](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scope-of-variables-python)

however, proper way to to get the result from your function would be:

```
def cube(x):
    return x * x * x

result = cube(3)

print(result)
```